Where to put cacert.pem certificate file so that ddev composer will use it? Getting "self signed certificate in certificate chain" error
I am using WSL2 with Ubuntu, following the procedure here: https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/quickstart/#__tabbed_2_2
When I get to the line ddev composer create "drupal/recommended-project:^9" it fails with Failed to download drupal/recommended-project from dist: curl error 60 while downloading https://api.github.com/repos/drupal/recommended-project/zipball/5844800af33c7a774999455d11d6de9307f878d8: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
According to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21187946/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-issue-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-cha you need to download the cacert.pem file from here: https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html I have done so, but where do I put this file in my WSL2/Ubuntu installation? I tried copying it to /usr/local/share/ca-certificates and then running sudo update-ca-certificates. I also tried adding new public keys for tags and dev verification from https://composer.github.io/pubkeys.html, but the error persists.
Here is my ddev composer diagnose output:
➜  my-drupal9-site ddev composer diagnose
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK git version 2.30.2
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] curl error 60 while downloading https://api.github.com/rate_limit: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys:
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
Checking composer version: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] curl error 60 while downloading    https://getcomposer.org/versions: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
Composer version: 2.6.6
PHP version: 8.1.27
PHP binary path: /usr/bin/php8.1
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1w  11 Sep 2023
cURL version: 7.74.0 libz 1.2.11 ssl OpenSSL/1.1.1w
zip: extension present, unzip present, 7-Zip not available
Composer [diagnose] failed, composer command failed: exit status 2. stderr=
➜  my-drupal9-site   


Are you connecting directly to the internet, or via a proxy?

I believe it is direct, because there is no http_proxy environment variable in the WSL2 Ubuntu shell. Also, if in the host PC I go to Control Panel --> Internet Options --> Connections --> LAN Settings --> Proxy server checkbox is NOT checked.

With assistance from this answer, I had to take my corporate certificate and append it to the end of the cacert.pem file.
I saved the new file to /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/, then ran sudo update-ca-certificates, and then everything worked!
